# Formatting Google Querystring to Dates

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications

I'm setting up an MVP PM dashboard for our Project Management team (using various google services) but keep running into a brick wall with the following query.

In the code below, (Snippet 2) column C and D needs to be in date format. The code in Snippet 2 executes like a charm for other charts that work with string and integer values, or when I hardcode the dates as in Snippet 1:

***Snippet 1***

```
['Task 1', 'Taks 1 B', new Date(2019, 0, 1), new Date(2019, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
```

but the moment I want to work with actual dates, the universe implodes.

The PM charts are generated using Googles Charting Services and require an array (data table) to generate the charts.

The dates are "pulled" from a google sheet with column C and D already in date format.

***How do I amend the queryString in Snippet 2 to format column C and D to dates?***

I've gone through the google.visualization API reference docs, but the examples there are well, yeah...

I've tried:

- ('SELECT format A, B, date(C), D, E, F, G'); error
- ('SELECT format A, B, year(C), D, E, F, G'); error
- ('SELECT A, B, format year(C), D, E, F, G'); error

I'm missing something crucial and feel like a complete chop.

***Snippet 2***

```
function drawChart() {
      var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G');
      var query = new google.visualization.Query('[ur][id]/gviz/tq?gid=0&headers=1&tq=' + queryString);
```

Comment: Do you get better results with select A, B, year(C), month(C), day(C)?

Comment: Hi @JeremyKahan, thanks for responding.
Read through a few more Google ref docs and found a solution:

`var queryString = encodeURIComponent('SELECT A, B, toDate(C), toDate(D), F, G, H WHERE A is not null');`

Comment: I am glad you found that